# Regard understanding a piece of perl code

Tags: perl

With respect to the following code segment,

```
foreach my $Index1 (sort { $A <=> $B } keys %{$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}})
{
if($dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}->{$Index1} == 2.0) { next }
    printf $sth
}
```

How to understand the `my $Index1 (sort { $A <=> $B } keys %{$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}})`  and  `($dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}->{$Index1} == 2.0)`

How to understand their underlying logic piece by piece? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `$a` and `$b` unless it doesn't compile.

Comment: You're allowed to cry about it - it is ghastly code.  It is a vastly complex structure; the local fragment of code should be simplified by creating a local reference to `$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}`.  It's a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) issue; would you spot if the variable in the `if` condition was accidentally changed to `$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index3]->{Vector}->{$Index1}`?

Comment: When I see something like this it to "use Data::Dumper" and "print Dumper $dat1" to see what the data structure looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It helps if you abstract the nested data structure away:

```
my $VectorHashRef = $dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector};
foreach my $Index1 (sort { $A <=> $B } keys %$VectorHashRef ) {
    # This should be corrected to $a <=> $b - names are case sensitive
    if ($VectorHashRef->{$Index1} == 2.0) { 
         next;
    }
    printf $sth;
}
```

`$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}` is a way to access some piece of data (a hashref) deep in a nested data structure. It takes a hashref `$dat1`, accesses the data structure that is pointed to by a hash key `"dat1"` - and that key points to an array reference. You take the value from that array with an index `$Index2` - and that value is a reference to the next data structure (hashref). You take the value of that hash for the key `"Vector"` - which is another hashref.

Now, let's alias that Vector hashref with `$VectorHashRef` variable (I'm using the word alias loosely).

Now, you are iterating over the keys of that hashref, sorted numerically (see Dan's answer for details on how that works), and for each key, comparing the hash value to `2.0`, printing something only if the value is NOT 2.0.

To understand this well, you need to read somee data structures in Perl tutorial - for example [Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (aka `perldoc perldsc`)

In short:

- When you see something that looks likie `EXPRESSION->{KEY_EXPRESSION}`, that means accessing the value (for a key specified by KEY_EXPRESSION) in a hashref, with the hash reference being the result of `EXPRESSION`.
- When you see something that looks likie `EXPRESSION->[INDEX_EXPRESSION]`, that means accessing the value (for a array subscript specified by INDEX_EXPRESSION) in an array reference, with the array reference being the result of `EXPRESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

`$dat1->{dat1}->[$Index2]->{Vector}` is a hash reference, and it's dereferenced by putting it in `%{}`.

The keys are being retrieved for that hash with `keys`.

Those keys are being sorted using a typical `cmp`/`<=>` operator in a block ([see `sort` documentation here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)). **Please note that your sorting code is actually broken - as noted in the documentation linked, special variables used in soriting's block must be `$a` and `$b` - lowercased**

The resulting list of sorted keys is being iterated through and assigned to `$Index1`.

If the value of the `$Index1` key in `Vector` is 2.0, then the key is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The variables used by `sort` are `$a` and `$b` in lower case; that code will not work properly because variables `$A` and `$B` are not set by the `sort` command before the comparison is executed.

It is time to compile the script with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.

Comment: +a for A/B vs a/b. Great catch

Answer (score 0):

- Loop `my`-scoped `$Index1` variable of the sorted array of keys of the hash, stored in `Vector` of the hash, stored at `$Index2` of the list put into `$dat1` has at `dat1`.
- check if the `$Index1` in the same hash is equal to 2.0

it may sound complicated, anyone can try to translate it into human language, but no one can understand it for you and it will take some effort on your side.